# How check encoding of file xml in php?

Tags: php

I want to check encoding of file xml is UTF-8.
How check encoding of this file xml in php?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with:

```
mb_check_encoding(file_get_contents("file.xml"), 'UTF-8');
```